# How to debug why uid,gid,umask,fmask and dmask mount options are ignored?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mount, fat32, vfat

I am running a Live ISO of Kubuntu 22.04 LTS (AKA Jammy Jellyfish). What I am trying to do has most likely nothing to do with KDE, so one may assume I am running Ubuntu.

I am trying to mount a `FAT32` partition in read-write mode for current user. On this Live ISO the user is called `kubuntu` (it is `ubuntu` in case of Ubuntu). There is also a `root` which always has all permissions, obviously. But I want to make it work for a regular user.

Lets assume I have the partition device path in shell variable `P` and mount point path in `MP`. I tried to execute such command

```
sudo mount $P $MP
```

Then when I call

```
mount | grep $MP
```

I can see such mount type and options applied (please note `fmask` and `dmask` options values):

```
type vfat (rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)
```

When I call `stat $MP | grep Uid:` I get this:

```
Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
```

It completely matches to what one would expect when doing mount as `root` when options with values like `fmask=0022,dmask=0022` have been applied.

I tried to find an information about how to make mounted FS work for a regular user. All the recommendations are about `uid`,`gid`,`umask`,`fmask`, `dmask` and how to use those. While I am pretty happy with `fmask=0022,dmask=0022` I also decided to try to reset those as well. So I ended up trying this (added redundancy, just in case):

```
sudo mount -o uid=$(id -u),gid=$(id -g),umask=0000,fmask=0000,dmask=0000 $P $MP
```

And guess what? The result is exactly the same as I mentioned above. It is

```
type vfat (rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)
```

Same thing with `stat $MP | grep Uid:`. It returns

```
Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
```

There are no write permissions for my `kubuntu` user.

I checked `sudo dmesg | tail -n 2` and `cat /var/log/syslog | tail -n 2`. I usually triggering "sysrq: Emergency Sync" by pressing `Alt+(SysRq/PrtScr, S)` right before I do something like above (`sudo mount ...`). This way I have a "checkpoint" in logs which consist of 2 lines with text fragments `sysrq: Emergency Sync` and `Emergency Sync complete`. So as usual I triggered "sysrq: Emergency Sync" and then called `sudo mount ...`. After checking both logs all I saw was just those 2 lines related to "sysrq: Emergency Sync". There is nothing related to `mount` command which would shed some light on why it ignored mount options.

So here are the questions:

- Why the mount options I provided were ignored?
- How to troubleshoot this kind of `mount` behavior?

Comment: Did you run those two `mount` commands with unmounting in between?

Comment: @muru , yes. Otherwise it would complain like `mount: /mnt/p: /dev/nvme0n1p10 already mounted on /mnt/p.`.